# Can't get port fowarding to work no matter what i try

Tags: connection, port-forwarding

I'm trying to access my Pi's Sabnzbd web server from the Internet but cannot. I can access Sabnzbd from local IPs successfully. The port forwarding does not seem to be working for my pi.

I did test remotely connecting from the Internet to Sabnzbd on my windows pc (using the same port with the windows pc local ip) and connected fine, so I know its not my ISP blocking the ports. My Pi connects to the internet fine. I have tried other things (Sickbeard, Coachpotato, VNC) with the same unsuccessful result.

I was able to get weave to work through the Internet but would rather not use this way.

Is it possible my Pi is blocking everything or is it likely a router issue?

Comment: Google the program name followed by "bind ip" then bind it to your public IP to allow for public access of your webserver

Comment: What does "sudo ufw status verbose" at the pi's terminal give you ?

Comment: Did you set up port forwarding on your router?

Comment: Could you tell us which port you are trying to forward? And also the brand/model of router?

Answer (score 1):

If you can access it locally then it sounds like a router issue that is causing it to fail over public network. You could try resin.io, it provides a really easy way to do web forwarding(it uses their VPN instead of your router so there is no setup) you can take a look here: http://docs.resin.io/runtime/runtime/#device-urls

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a router/modem issue. depending on your router you should be able to sign in and add port forwarding to any devices. I am in Canada with Shaw. I go to 10.0.0.1 and can access this.Because there are endless kinds of routers out there if you arent sure how to login to your router contact your provider first. There may also be some login credentials on the bottom or back of the router/modem

[General Port Forwarding Guide](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/general-port-forwarding-guide/)

[Understanding Port Forwarding: A Beginners Guide](https://stevessmarthomeguide.com/understanding-port-forwarding/)

[My personal fave! portforwarding.com](https://portforward.com/)